# TextMate: Shortcut for switching focus between editor and project drawer

Tags: macos, osx-lion, textmate

I'm looking for a shortcut for switching focus between editor and project drawer in TextMate. I googled a bit with different results, but none of the shortcuts is working for me:

http://dirtystylus.com/2007/10/26/toggling-between-main-window-and-drawer-in-textmate/
http://gtdmarc.blogspot.de/2008/06/some-useful-textmate-shortcuts.html

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/343773/focusing-the-drawer-in-textmate-on-lion) link suggest installing the MissingDrawer Plugin, but but that's not the solution I'm looking for.

I have OS X Lion 10.7.3 and TextMate 1.5.10 on a MacBook Pro with a German keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it, it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>.

Comment: This shortcut doesn't work for me, but I found a simpler solution (which is in line with many other editors): <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut in TextMate 2 (using a spanish keyboard) is `ctrl` + `tab`.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer is in the docs:

> ⌘` ⌘~ Switch to the next/previous window. This keyboard shortcut is based on the physical location of the key so on many European keymaps it is instead ⌘< and ⌘> (it is the key to the left of the Z).
>
> ⌥⌘` ⌥⌘~ Switch between main window and drawer. Like the previous key this one is also based on physical location. The function is not available on Panther.

***EDIT***

Both have been working for me on my french keyboard but not how the docs said: neither <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> nor <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> did work but <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> did. YMMV.

***ENDEDIT***

Answer (score 0):

In 2.0-beta <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> works fine. It's equivalent of Navigate->Move focus to file browser